# How do I use $rotate3d with create-transform?

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I'm trying to use `$rotate3d` inside of a `create-transform` block (along with scale-x) and nothing I try is working quite right. If I do just `rotate3d` like this, it works beautifully:

`@include rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 3deg, 800);`

But I need to combine this with scale and perspective, so create-transform is my only option.

It's the multiple argument thing for `$rotate3d` that's getting me. I tried this but it didn't work:

```
@include create-transform(
    $rotate3d: "1, 0, 0, 30deg, 800"
);
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arguments to mixins are separated by commas, so Sass thinks you are trying to send a single value to the `$rotate3d` argument.  What you're actually wanting to do is send a comma delimited list as the value for a single argument.  That can be done by adding parentheses around the list:

```
@include create-transform($rotate3d: (1, 0, 0, 30deg, 800));
```